Second monitor detected but not working
I have a PC with Ubuntu 22 and a NVIDIA graphic card. When I plug the second monitor, it is detected but it stays black. The Xorg log show:

[ 54734.333] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for
pci:0000:05:00.0: -2
[ 54734.333] Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.   Configuration failed.
[ 54734.333]
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.

This is the output of nvidia-smi:

This is the content of /etc/X11/xorg.conf:
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath   "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    VendorName "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName  "Monitor Model"
    HorizSync  30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh 50.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor1"
    VendorName "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName  "Monitor Model"
    HorizSync  30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh 50.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:5:0:0"
    Option      "SLI" "Off"
    Option      "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option      "BaseMosaic" "on"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
        Modes    "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
        Modes    "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

This is the output of xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       72.81    59.94  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Notice: if I try to run xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --primary --output DP-3 --auto --right-of HDMI-0, I only see the HDMI monitor (as usual), with all the active windows missing and the DP monitor staying black.
How can I fix this problem?
EDIT: the Xorg log says

Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"

but this file does not exist.

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead ... format as code for readability
